# Determine if a line segment intersects a polygon

Tags: python, geometry, polygon

If I have a vector (a line consisting of 2 points) on a 2D plane how can I determine if it has passed through a polygon?

I know I can take each line which makes up the polygon and see if any intersect but is there a better way?

I've read this one post [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test) which gives me some ideas for seeing whether the point is within a polygon but I need to see if it has passed over/intersected it.

Comment: You need to determine if the line intersects any of the edges of the polygon or includes one of its vertices. Depending on what you're doing this can often be speeded up by calculating a bounding circle for each polygon ahead of time and first checking whether the line intersects that to quickly reject whole polygons.

Answer (score 22):

If you want a python library for geometric operations, have a look at [`shapely`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely).  It makes this as simple as `someline.intersects(somepolygon)`.

Here's a quick example of intersections, buffer, and clipping (with a nice plot... I'm using [`descartes`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes) to easily convert shapely polygons into matplotlib patches.).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry
import descartes

circle = shapely.geometry.Point(5.0, 0.0).buffer(10.0)
clip_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon([[-9.5, -2], [2, 2], [3, 4], [-1, 3]])
clipped_shape = circle.difference(clip_poly)

line = shapely.geometry.LineString([[-10, -5], [15, 5]])
line2 = shapely.geometry.LineString([[-10, -5], [-5, 0], [2, 3]])

print 'Blue line intersects clipped shape:', line.intersects(clipped_shape)
print 'Green line intersects clipped shape:', line2.intersects(clipped_shape)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(*np.array(line).T, color='blue', linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round')
ax.plot(*np.array(line2).T, color='green', linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round')
ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(clipped_shape, fc='blue', alpha=0.5))
ax.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

This yields:

```
Blue line intersects clipped shape: True
Green line intersects clipped shape: False
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work with 3D geometry? (Or even N-denominational geometry?)

Answer (score 3):

Line crosses the polygon if and only if it crosses one of its edges (ignoring for a second the cases when it passes through a vertex). So, in your case you just need to test all edges of your polygon against your line and see if there's an intersection.

It is easy to test whether an edge `(a, b)` intersects a line. Just build a line equation for your line in the following form

```
Ax + By + C = 0
```

and then calculate the value `Ax + By + C` for points `a` and `b`. If the signs of theses values for `a` and `b` are different, then edge `(a, b)` intersects the line.

All that's left is to work out a way to handle the cases when the line passes through a vertex (endpoint of an edge), but it is easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care too much about efficiency, you can simply test for line intersection given your two reference points and all adjacent point pairs on the polygon.  Once you detect an intersection, you know that your line intersects with the polygon.

A good starting point is, as always, wikipedia:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection

So, lets run through an example

```
function line-polygon_intersection:
   Given points p0, p1 on plane P (your reference line)
   Given points q0..qn on plane P (the polygon)
   foreach ( qi, qi+1 ) pair of adjacent points:
      if line( p0, p1 ) intersects line( qi, qi+1 ):
          return true
   return false
```

And don't forget to cycle around with ( qn, q0 ) to close the poly!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a quick is point in polygon algorithm? Using one, you could determine if exactly one of the points is inside, which might also means intersection. If they both lie outside, one of the other methods is still required.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on an [answer by Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6052144/7380827) to this question.
I have modified the code such that it is working with Python 3. There also was the problem that the current implementation of shaply/numpy/matplotlib is not compatible with the code. There also was another problem with descartes. This version does not depend on descartes. I have tried to reproduce the same look.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050392/determine-if-a-line-segment-intersects-a-polygon
# modified for python 3, incl. fixes
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry

circle = shapely.geometry.Point(5.0, 0.0).buffer(10.0)
clip_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon([[-9.5, -2], [2, 2], [3, 4], [-1, 3]])
clipped_shape = circle.difference(clip_poly)

line = shapely.geometry.LineString([[-10, -5], [15, 5]])
line2 = shapely.geometry.LineString([[-10, -5], [-5, 0], [2, 3]])

print('Blue line intersects clipped shape:', line.intersects(clipped_shape))
print('Green line intersects clipped shape:', line2.intersects(clipped_shape))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(*np.array(line.coords.xy), color='blue', linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round')
ax.plot(*np.array(line2.coords.xy), color='green', linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round')
plt.fill(*np.array(clipped_shape.boundary.coords.xy), facecolor=(0.49,0.49,1), edgecolor=(0.49,0.49,1), linewidth=3)
ax.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```