# Return a Boolean if Line intersects a Polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

How can I have my list of lines return a list of booleans when they intersect a polygon, and as a result, don't show lines that return a True value?

Currently my code draws a line from the origin (0,0) to all the points on the XY cartesian plane. I want to be able to have the lines that intersect with a polygon return a boolean value. This will hopefully allow me to not display lines that return a True value.

i.e.
IF Lineintersection == True:
Don't display Line
ELSE:
Display Line

```
origin = [0,0]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import descartes

quality = 7
x = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
polycoords = [[-1, 1], [-1, 0.5], [0, 0.5], [0, 1]]
clip_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon(polycoords)

positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])

#plt.scatter(*positions[::-1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(len(positions)):
    for j in range(len(positions[i])):
        plt.scatter(*positions[::-1])
        x1 = positions[0][j]
        y1 = positions[1][j]
        line = LineString([origin, (x1, y1)])
        x2, y2 = line.xy
        lines = plt.plot(0, 0, x2, y2, color='green', linewidth=1, solid_capstyle='round')
        polygon = Polygon(polycoords)
        polygonbuilding = ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(clip_poly, fc='pink', alpha=0.3))
plt.show()
```

[Result from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMCGK.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if a line segment intersects a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050392/determine-if-a-line-segment-intersects-a-polygon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you can simplify your code by removing the polygon creation from the two `for` loops, for example by creating the polygon before creating the lines (also, note that your are creating it two times in your original code, once in the `clip_poly` variable and once ine the `polygon` variable).

Then you will be able to call the [`intersects`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.intersects) method of the geometry objets your are handling (here `polygon` and `line`).

I simplified your two `for` loop in one loop, unpacking directly the `x1` and `y1` coordinates (and I also moved the `plt.scatter` call outside of the loop):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import descartes

origin = [0,0]
quality = 7
x = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,quality)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
polycoords = [[-1, 1], [-1, 0.5], [0, 0.5], [0, 1]]
positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

polygon = Polygon(polycoords)
polygonbuilding = ax.add_patch(
    descartes.PolygonPatch(polygon, fc='pink', alpha=0.3))
plt.scatter(*positions[::-1])
    
for x1, y1 in positions.T:
    line = LineString([origin, (x1, y1)])
    if not polygon.intersects(line):  # <- the condition you were looking for
        x2, y2 = line.xy
        plt.plot(0, 0, x2, y2, color='green', linewidth=1, solid_capstyle='round')

plt.show()
```

[image: ResultPlot]